# what maxmind geoip ruby wrapper is up2date and usable? ( for the commercial library )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, geolocation, geoip

Im trying to get below github repo in my app

```
https://github.com/mtodd/geoip
```

Ive tried adding it like

```
gem "geoip", :git => "git://github.com/mtodd/geoip.git"
```

Error =

```
Could not find gem 'geoip (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/mtodd/geoip.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'geoip (>= 0) ruby'
```

**Is there are ruby gem wrapper for GeoIP that is compatible with the LATEST GEOIP?**
Ive searched very long for one, the one above seems to be sort off compatible with 1.4.7 and higher but I can't get it installed, any other suggestion? Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in my Gemfile:

```
gem "geoip-c", '~> 0.7.1', :git => "git://github.com/mtodd/geoip.git"
```

As far as I know, it's totally compatible.

Comment: I came across this lateron  and indeed that one seem to work fine, thx. the git part doesn't work for me though but without it goes well

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a few years ago, but I recently had trouble finding a good up-to-date gem for this. What I found was [Geoip2 by YotpoLtd](https://github.com/YotpoLtd/geoip2).

**In my Gemfile**

```
gem 'geoip2'
```

**Setting/Configuring**

```
Geoip2.configure do |conf|
     # Mandatory
     conf.license_key = 'Your MaxMind License Key'
     conf.user_id = 'Your MaxMind User Id'

     # Optional
    conf.host = 'geoip.maxmind.com' # Or any host that you would like to work with
    conf.base_path = '/geoip/v2.0' # Or any other version of this API
    conf.parallel_requests = 5 # Or any other amount of parallel requests that you would like to use
end
```

**Using**

```
data = Geoip2.omni('0.0.0.0') #this call is synchronous
```

*note: I believe you can replace 'omni' with the name of the product tier: city, country, etc

**Errors**
If there is an error, the returned hash will have an error object, so simply check for its existence

```
if data.error
    # error handling
else #still might want to check for data's existence ( if data )
    #access object as you will
    data.city.names.en
    data.postal.code
end
```

For more information about the returned hash, see the [MaxMind Web Services Documentation](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/)